# Cannot cast singleton class to an interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting, singleton

I have a `Logger` class which is implemented singleton. The class is simple and there are few methods and one `static` property, `Instance`. Like all singleton classes, I access the unique instance via `Logger.Instance` property.

I extracted an interface from `Logger` class (using Visual Studio refactor context menu). After extraction, interface contains signature for those few methods, and since the `Instance` property is `static`, it is not included in `ILogger` interface.

After all of this, I cannot cast a `Logger.Instance` into `ILogger` at run-time. What is wrong with my approach ?

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: The point was, since I extracted the interface after writing the Logger, I forgot to implement the interface by Logger. I meant I was not planned at first mind-set. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually declare that `Logger` implements `ILogger`?

```
public sealed class Logger : ILogger
{
    ...
}
```

If so, it should be fine. Please post some code so we can try to diagnose the issue.

If not, that's the problem, and it's easily fixed :)

Comment: It's a kind of intelligence to guess what are the common mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example you described works fine for me. I made a small example, maybe you see some differences:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ILogger logger = Logger.GetLogger();
        logger.LogMessage("Hello");
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void LogMessage(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private static Logger instance;

    public static Logger GetLogger()
    {
        return instance ?? (instance = new Logger());
    }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```